# Rendering client side charts on the server

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, flot, dashboard

The product I'm working on has some nice graphs on a HTML5 dashboard. The graphs are rendered in Javascript using [Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org).

Users would like this Dashboard emailed to them daily as a PDF report, on a fixed schedule. So for example they want an email every day at 8am to be emailed to them.

I've thought of using Python's [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) (i.e. do a `request.get`) to get the HTML5 source of the page and then convert the resulting HTML5 page to PDF using [Weasyprint](http://weasyprint.org) but this is obviously not going to work.

The Javascript charts are the biggest headache as they won't render unless viewed in a browser that has decent Javascript support, so the outlined approach won't render the Javascript graphs.

What's the recommended way of converting a dynamically generated HTML5 page into PDF? How do other people do this?

Comment: You can use [toDataUrl()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) method to achieve this

Comment: It's not going to work because I need something on the server side that renders the Canvas and supports Javascript.

Comment: You can use this  method to convert your canvas into image data and submit it to server. Then on server side use any pdf library e.g. [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) to generate a pdf with this image as part of it. Use that pdf to be send as a mail or whatever

Comment: Given that there is going to be no interaction from the client, no browser involved, how will I render this Javascript chart? This is the hard bit. Once I solve that, everything else is easy.

Comment: oh I did not realise there is not going to be any client involvement, sorry. In that case why dont you generate chart on server side itself. i had worked on this problem also few years ago using [JFree](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) library for java. Which language are you working on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) is the solution. It's a headless WebKit implementation that allows us to render to PDF the dashboards with Javascript graphs and all.

I've now set up a batch job that will run every day to convert our dashboards to a PDF document that gets emailed to the users.

**Addendum**

Some other things to be aware off. In the current 2.1 build of PhantomJS, there is a bug that causes renders to PDF to clip. The fix is scheduled for 2.2. A temporary workaround as detailed on the [bug report](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12685#issuecomment-202881894) is to set the CSS zoom level of the document. The following CSS fragment works for me.

```
html {
    zoom: 50%;
}
```